# Deutsche Ausgabe von "A river of Grass" von Marjorie Stoneman Douglas

Tags: translation, book

Wurde das Buch *A River of Grass* von Marjory Stoneman Douglas jemals ins Deutsche übersetzt? Und wenn es übersetzt wurde, wurde *Ein Fluss von Gras* als Titel verwendet?

Comment: Die Schriftstellerin ist komplett unbekannt in Deutschland (abgesehen von einer gewissen traurigen Berühmtheit als Namensgeberin der Schule, an der das Parkland-Attentat verübt wurde). Es ist unwahrscheinlich, dass eines ihrer Bücher jemals ins Deutsche übersetzt wurde.

Comment: Außerdem ist das Thema (die *Everglades*) von geringer Bedeutung in Deutschland, im Gegensatz zu internationalen Fachbüchern oder schlicht fiktionalen Büchern. Das könnte meiner Meinung nach auch ein Grund dafür sein, dass es - trotz gewisser Bekanntheit (?) - wohl zu keiner Übersetzung gekommen ist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not directly related to the german language.

Comment: Es gibt keine Spur im Internet, dass überhaupt ein Buch der Schriftstellerin ja ins Deutsche übersetzt wurde. Normalerweise wäre so was auf jeden Fall auf Amazon Deutschland zu finden. Ich denke aber auch, dass das off-topic ist.

Comment: And die Off-topic-Voter: Fällt euch denn überhaupt nicht auf, dass der Fragestellen bei dem vermuteten deutschen Titel einen Grammatikfehler gemacht hat? Die Frage, ob »Ein Fluss von Gras« ein deutscher Buchtitel sein könnte, ist keineswegs off-topic.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Dann sollte der OP seine Frage so umformulieren, dass die Frage nach der möglichen Übersetzung des Buchtitels in den Vordergrund rückt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich habe mir überlegt, ob ich auf den Fehler eingehen soll, dann aber entschieden, dass das nicht der Kern der Frage war. Wenn es keine deutsche Übersetzung gibt, scheint mir die Frage nach ihrem Titel irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

- **Wurde das Buch jemals ins Deutsche übersetzt?**
  Eine Recherche im Internet, bei verschiedenen Online-Buchhändlern lieferte brachte keine einzige Übersetzung eines Buches von Marjorie Stoneman Douglas zutage, egal in welche Sprache. Ich gehe daher davon aus, dass es keine solche Übersetzung gibt.
- **»Ein Fluss von Gras« als Titel?**
  Das kann ich definitiv ausschließen, denn das wäre kein grammatisch korrekter deutscher Buchtitel.

  Der englische Titel bedeutet ja, dass es einen Fluss gibt, der aus einem anderem Material als Wasser besteht, nämlich aus Gras. Die richtige Präposition, um das Material anzugeben aus dem etwas besteht, ist aber nicht *von* sondern *aus.* Das Buch müsste also so heißen:

  > Die Everglades
  >   Ein Fluss **aus** Gras

  Natürlich unter der Voraussetzung, dass der englische Titel wörtlich ins Deutsche übersetzt wird, was ja oftmals nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: Üblicherweise werden solche Konstrukte im Deutschen mit einem zusammengesetzten Substantiv wiedergegeben, also: *Ein Grasfluss*.

Comment: Danke vielmals. Das Buch wurde fast sicher nie ins Deutsche übersetzt, weil es kurz nach dem Ende des Zweiten Weltkriegs (1947) geschrieben wurde und es in Deutschland keinen Markt dafür gegeben hätte. Danke auch an die Leute, die bemerkt haben, dass ich "von Gras" geschrieben habe, wenn "aus Gras" besser ist. Das Buch bleibt in den USA in gedruckter Form und gilt als "Klassiker" der Umweltwissenschaften.

Comment: Ein gräserner Fluss??? ;)